# Mini pager on View in a block does not work

Tags: views, 6, blocks

I have a view that is displayed on a rightside block using quicktabs.

In Quicktabs it is the third option and set up as a view (as opposed to set up as a block).

It lists authors on a blog, and has a pagination feature. The mini pagination DOES show up, it just doesn't do anything. The pagination link appears but doesn't actually effect the view in the quicktab.

I've tried changing the Views ajax feature both on and off and neither have an effect.

Comment: Try updating to the latest .dev version of Views. I had an indirectly similar issue with pager not accepting an override in the block display of a view and the update corrected my issue. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so this was a major undertaking, and in fact had nothing to do with using Quicktabs.

The issue was two-fold in my case.
The names were being aggregated in Views using the Arguments section with a List style. THIS is what was breaking ajax pagination.

I added the development version of the 'Views Group By' module to do the aggregation instead of using the Arguments section, and that worked.

In addition, I have a module called 'Secure Pages' that was causing a 302 redirect on the ajax request. I had to white-list `/views/ajax*` to overcome this error.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you want pagination to work as being a block display, you will have to set `Use AJAX` to `Yes` under Basic settings in your view edit page.

In the page display Pager work as it receives parameter as query string variable `?page=1`.

Comment: I updated my question before you answered... sorry! But I've narrowed down the issue further than just views. I believe it is a quicktabs/views issue.

Comment: Oh ya, I submitted 33 minutes ago and you updated 32 minutes what I am looking now :)